# Sound crackling on Arch after installing android-studio

Tags: arch-linux, audio, android

I installed android studio for flutter app development and after that sound from any source starts crackling every 5-10s. Sounds starts crackling only when I open something that is related with flutter, like VS Code with flutter extension. I am using pipewire-pulse.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem, I think. I don't use Android Studio, but I installed to set up VSCode for Flutter app development.

I'm on Pop!_OS with pipewire.

The sound is crackling in any application, like MS Teams or Spotify. It isn't always there. When I closed emulator and VS Code it stopped, but when I restarted them the crackling did not return.

Comment: I also had these issues that you have. I tried a lot of different things to solve this problem: I tried a bunch of distros but on every one of them this problem occurred, I tried pipewire and pulse, I tried killing android-gradle plugin, and then it stopped crackling, but then flutter didn't work… this was 4 months ago. So maybe something changed, but I didn’t have time to get back to flutter. I hope that you will solve it.  If I find any fix for it, I am going to post it here as an answer.

Comment: It seem to be enough to close the emulator. I'm not even sure all emulators causes the issue, but Nexus 10 API 30 does. I can live with it, it is just a bit annoying.

Comment: I found this : https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-troubleshoot-crackling-in-pipewire/82442 but haven't managed to fix the crackling from it yet